# webpack doesn't reload when code changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

There is a project for react, everything is configured, other developers all work fine, but I do not have automatic page updates when I save.

webpack.config.js

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ] : [],
  output: {
    path: './public/js',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/js'
  },
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 100
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style!css"
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map"
};
```

package.json

```js
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build --env=production",
  "test_build": "react-scripts build --env=testing",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

[tcp3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ0nv.png)

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console? Or terminal?

Comment: Is it possible that when you started the dev server that the port is already in use?

Comment: There are errors in the browser console, there is no terminal

Comment: I do not know about the port, deployed the project on a clean ubuntu

Comment: I think there are no errors in the console for reloading

Comment: It appears you (or someone else) bootstrapped the project with create-react-app. Assuming you started the dev server with `npm start` (or `yarn start`) the default port is 3000, and you should access your dev server in http://localhost:3000. More details in [CRA's Readme](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-start)

Comment: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#webstorm
did as here, does not help